# How to change the color of v-badge in different status?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new in Vue.js.How to change the badge in vuetify with different color?I want the badge of "in" status to appear in green, "fresh" status appear in yellow, "wait" status appear in grey.

https://codepen.io/magooo/pen/wvgjLRb

```js
{
  name: "Frozen Yogurt",
  calories: 159,
  status: "in", // color yellow
},
{
  name: "Ice cream sandwich",
  calories: 237,
  status: "fresh", // color green
},
{
  name: "Eclair",
  calories: 262,
  status: "fresh", // color green
},
{
  name: "Cupcake",
  calories: 305,
  status: "wait", // color grey
}
```

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot! But is it possible to use "watch" to differentiate the color by string (e.g.,in,fresh,wait) in vue rather than add color property in types array? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can do a mapping between the status and the color yeah, but it will require more code, will be less "clean" (since you're using vuetify and that it's wired like this there) and will also be less performant. What's the issue of adding such property in the array ?

Answer (score 1):

Hosted solution: https://codepen.io/kissu-the-styleful/pen/MWJXBJM?editors=1010

Here is how you can achieve it

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <div>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="types"
          class="elevation-0 mx-10 my-10"
          :hide-default-footer="true"
        >
          <template #[`body`]="{ items }">
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
                <td>
                  <v-badge bordered bottom :color="item.color" dot offset-x="10" offset-y="10"></v-badge>
                  {{ item.status }}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </div>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "name", value: "name" },
        { text: "calories", value: "calories" },
        { text: "status", value: "status" },
      ],
      types: [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          status: "in",
          color: "yellow",
        },
        {
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237,
          status: "fresh",
          color: "green",
        },
        {
          name: "Eclair",
          calories: 262,
          status: "fresh",
          color: "green",
        },
        {
          name: "Cupcake",
          calories: 305,
          status: "wait",
          color: "blue-grey",
        }
      ]
    };
  },
})
```

Essentially making `:color="item.color"` dynamic depending of the `types` object.

PS: `:color` is a shorthand for `v-bind:color`